# Spring Hibernate find all records that have value in set

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have entity Doctor

```
@Entity
    public class Doctor extends Account {         
    //other attributes
    @Column
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Speciality.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Speciality> speciality = new HashSet<Speciality>(0);        
    //getters and setters
    }
```

and entity Speciality

```
@Entity
    public class Speciality {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    String name;
    //getters and setters here
}
```

Now in my application user can choose speciality of doctor that want to visit. For example user choose 
endocrinologist and now my application needs to find all doctors that have speciality endocrinologist in Set speciality. **How to do this?**

Comment: Hey @implssv. Please give me feedback about my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40060198/2650174). If it's work for you mark it as accepted.

Comment: Every answers works fine but you wrote something more about good practices :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it using **[Hibernate Criteria Queries Builder API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)**:

```
final List<Doctor> doctors = getSession()
       .createCriteria(Doctor.class, "doc")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("doc.speciality.id", specialityId))
       .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
       .list();
```

Comment: Don't use the criteria API for simple cases. The only reason to use it in this case is to make the life unnecessary hard. Since he uses Spring he should use spring-data-jpa.

Comment: @mh-dev I agree that Spring Data JPA is better. But Hibernate Criteria it's actually good for simple query like this. Here is not so many columns in result set and query will quickly executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use elements:

```
SELECT d
    FROM Doctor d
    WHERE 
        :spec IN elements(d.speciality)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the MEMBER OF JPQL statement.

For example:

```
Select d From Doctor d where :speciality MEMBER OF d.speciality
```